# Modules with special properties

Tags: rt.representation-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, modules, gap

$\DeclareMathOperator\End{End}$Let $A$ be a finite dimensional algebra and $M$ an indecomposable (right) module with the property that every nilpotent element of $\End_A(M)$ annihilates the socle $\mathrm{soc}_A(M)$ of $M$. Note that $M$ is an $\End_A(M)$ left module.

> Question: Are there equivalent characterisations for modules $M$ with this property, possibly only using the right $A$-module structure of $M$? Is it possible to check whether a given module has this property using the GAP-package QPA?

Such modules are considered in "On algebras of finite representation type" by Spencer Dickson, Trans. AMS 1969 ([link at AMS site](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1969-135-00/S0002-9947-1969-0237558-9/S0002-9947-1969-0237558-9.pdf)).

Answer (score 2):

This might do the trick. Updated version compared to the first version. Tested on two examples, so might not work in general.

```
test := function( M )
  local EndM, radEndM, BradEndM, BradHomMM, socM, BsocM, m, f;

  EndM := EndOverAlgebra( M );
  radEndM := RadicalOfAlgebra( EndM );
  BradEndM := BasisVectors( Basis( radEndM ) );
  if Length( BradEndM ) = 0 then
    return true;
  fi;
  BradHomMM := [];
  for b in BradEndM do
    Add( BradHomMM, FromEndMToHomMM( M, b ) );
  od;
  socM := SocleOfModuleInclusion( M );
  BsocM := BasisVectors( Basis( Source( socM ) ) );
  BsocM := List( BsocM, b -> ImageElm( socM, b ) );
  
  for m in BsocM do 
    for f in BradHomMM do
      if ImageElm( f, m ) <> Zero( m ) then
        return false;
      fi;
    od;
  od;
  
  return true;
end;
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I tested it a bit. For the algebra A:=NakayamaAlgebra([3,4],GF(3)); it gives an error when applied to the indecomposable projective modules.